# Show that the map is $\mathbb{C}$-linear

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a $\mathbb{R}$-linear map. I want to show that the map $F:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^m$ $x\mapsto F(x):=f(x)-if(ix)$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear.

Since $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear we have that $f(z_1+z_2)=f(z_1)+f(z_2), \forall z_1, z_2\in \mathbb{C}$ and $f(\lambda z)=\lambda f(z), \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, z\in \mathbb{C}$.

To show that $F$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear, we have to show that $F(z_1+z_2)=F(z_1)+F(z_2), \forall z_1, z_2\in \mathbb{C}$ and $F(\lambda z)=\lambda F(z), \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{C}, z\in \mathbb{C}$, right?

We have that \begin{align*}F(z_1+z_2)&=f(z_1+z_2)-if(i(z_1+z_2))\\ &  \overset{ f :\mathbb{R}-\text{linear} }{ = } \ f(z_1)+f(z_2)-if(iz_1+iz_2) \\ & =f(z_1)+f(z_2)-i[f(iz_1)+f(iz_2)] \\ & =f(z_1)-if(iz_1)+f(z_2)-if(iz_2)\\ & =F(z_1)+F(z_2)\end{align*}

Is this correct? Or is it better to substitute $z=a+bi$ ?

How can we show the second property, i.e. that $F(\lambda z)=\lambda F(z)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is good .Now if c is a real number it's also routine in a similar way to show F(cx)=cF(x) .In particular F(-x)=-F(x) .The main point is to show for x complex that F(ix)=iF(x) . Plug in ix for x in your formula for F and remembering ii=-1 .It's fun to see it work out -you do it.